# Is there a way in python to make a list with the minimum weight of each path between two data points without tooking much time?

Tags: python, graph, path, cluster-computing, similarity

I need to do the following thing:

Given a fully connected graph I want to calculate the path similarity between each pair of vertices.

To do that for a pair ($i$, $j$) is needed to take the the maximum value of the set of the minimum edge weight for each path starting in $i$ and ending in $j$.

Obviously is possible to consider all paths between $i$ and $j$ take the minimum edge weight then take the maximum between the minimum edges weights, but this takes too long for a large graph. Does someone know a way to do this faster?

Thanks.

Comment: This problem is not about programming and might make more sense on a different StackExchange site (math.stackexchange.com, maybe?). Also, the way it is formulated now (fully connected graph, min edge out of all path) it will always be the smallest edge in the graph.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for, maybe, a code that could do that. Maybe my formulation is a little messed up, but what I wanted to say is: in each path take the value of the minimum edge, then take the maximum value between this all minimum values. So, in resume, I need to compute a list that has the value of the minimum edge weight for each path, than take the maximum value of this list. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: Post a sample of the graph and the expected outcome. I'll try to sketch something

Comment: Marat your suggestion on asking my problem in math.stackexchange was wonderful. People there found this: Widest path problem. Which is the same as I have, so now I'm restricting my search for finding a good algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: It can be solved with a modification of Dijkstra. The only difference is that instead of increasing the distance by edge length you take min of edge width and path leading to the previous node

Comment: yes! Thank you (: